# how to obtain this value into a variable for later manipulation?

Tags: powershell

I found this code online and everything works but I don't know how to obtain the value of the output given in the execution, this script is for obtaining the text of images and it does give me the text but shows something like this "text of the image is..." and I don't know if it is all the text in the image or there's something missing

I've tried with |Out-file "path of file" but it shows the same text as mentioned above :/

Thank you for your help!

```
using namespace Windows.Storage
using namespace Windows.Graphics.Imaging

<#
.Synopsis
   Runs Windows 10 OCR on an image.
.DESCRIPTION
   Takes a path to an image file, with some text on it.
   Runs Windows 10 OCR against the image.
   Returns an [OcrResult], hopefully with a .Text property containing the text
.EXAMPLE
   $result = .\Get-Win10OcrTextFromImage.ps1 -Path 'c:\test.bmp'
   $result.Text
#>
[CmdletBinding()]
Param
(
    # Path to an image file
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
                ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, 
                Position=0,
                HelpMessage='Path to an image file, to run OCR on')]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    $Path
)

Begin {
    # Add the WinRT assembly, and load the appropriate WinRT types
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime

    $null = [Windows.Storage.StorageFile,                Windows.Storage,         ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
    $null = [Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine,                Windows.Foundation,      ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
    $null = [Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`1,       Windows.Foundation,      ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
    $null = [Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap,    Windows.Foundation,      ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
    $null = [Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStream, Windows.Storage.Streams, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
    
    
    # [Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine]::AvailableRecognizerLanguages
    $ocrEngine = [Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine]::TryCreateFromUserProfileLanguages()
    

    # PowerShell doesn't have built-in support for Async operations, 
    # but all the WinRT methods are Async.
    # This function wraps a way to call those methods, and wait for their results.
    $getAwaiterBaseMethod = [WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMember('GetAwaiter').
                                Where({
                                        $PSItem.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1'
                                    }, 'First')[0]

    Function Await {
        param($AsyncTask, $ResultType)

        $getAwaiterBaseMethod.
            MakeGenericMethod($ResultType).
            Invoke($null, @($AsyncTask)).
            GetResult()
    }
}

Process
{
    foreach ($p in $Path)
    {
      
        # From MSDN, the necessary steps to load an image are:
        # Call the OpenAsync method of the StorageFile object to get a random access stream containing the image data.
        # Call the static method BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync to get an instance of the BitmapDecoder class for the specified stream. 
        # Call GetSoftwareBitmapAsync to get a SoftwareBitmap object containing the image.
        #
        # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging#save-a-softwarebitmap-to-a-file-with-bitmapencoder

        # .Net method needs a full path, or at least might not have the same relative path root as PowerShell
        $p = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($p)
        
        $params = @{ 
            AsyncTask  = [StorageFile]::GetFileFromPathAsync($p)
            ResultType = [StorageFile]
        }
        $storageFile = Await @params


        $params = @{ 
            AsyncTask  = $storageFile.OpenAsync([FileAccessMode]::Read)
            ResultType = [Streams.IRandomAccessStream]
        }
        $fileStream = Await @params


        $params = @{
            AsyncTask  = [BitmapDecoder]::CreateAsync($fileStream)
            ResultType = [BitmapDecoder]
        }
        $bitmapDecoder = Await @params


        $params = @{ 
            AsyncTask = $bitmapDecoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync()
            ResultType = [SoftwareBitmap]
        }
        $softwareBitmap = Await @params

        # Run the OCR
        Await $ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync($softwareBitmap) ([Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrResult])

    }
}
```

Comment: Try debugging. Set the debugging point at the start of the script and move through the script line by line.

Comment: I know where the value is set but I don't know how to obtain it 

is either here:

 Function Await {
        param($AsyncTask, $ResultType)

        $getAwaiterBaseMethod.
            MakeGenericMethod($ResultType).
            Invoke($null, @($AsyncTask)).
            GetResult()
    }

or here 
 Await $ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync($softwareBitmap) ([Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrResult])

Comment: Pipe to `Format-List` to avoid the truncation of column values that can happen with (implicit) `Format-Table` (tabular) output. To save to a file without truncation (with the tabular format), pass  a `-Width` value to `Out-File` that is wide enough.

Comment: I don't know how to mark your answer as correct, but this was it! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
Await $ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync($softwareBitmap) ([Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrResult])
```

to

```
$result = Await $ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync($softwareBitmap) ([Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrResult])
[PSCustomObject]@{
    File  = $Path
    Lines = $result.lines.text
    Words = $result.lines.words.text
    Text  = $result | select -ExpandProperty text
}
```

And you'll end up with an object with members containing filename, all text, all lines, and all words